# Берем значение из импута и плюсуем с суммой, как считать не отводя мышку с импута?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать подсчет в реальном времени, вводим в импут число, после я беру его и плюсую к сумме и вывожу результат, если я ввожу в импут числа то ничего не считает, так сказать без отвода мышки чтоб считало.

Так сказать, без отвода мышки из импута.

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    const sum = 500;
    const priceDoplata = $("#priceDoplata").val();

    $('#sumcalc').html(+sum + +priceDoplata);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Сумма доплаты</strong><br />
 <input style="font-weight:bold;width: 150px; color: #FF2525" type="number" name="priceDoplata" id="priceDoplata" value="500">
 
<br /><br />

<div id="sumcalc"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    calc();
});

$('#priceDoplata').on('keyup change',() => {
    calc();
})
  
let calc = () => {
  const sum = 500;
  const priceDoplata = $("#priceDoplata").val();

  $('#sumcalc').html(+sum + +priceDoplata);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Сумма доплаты</strong><br />
 <input style="font-weight:bold;width: 150px; color: #FF2525" type="number" name="priceDoplata" id="priceDoplata" value="500">
 
<br /><br />

<div id="sumcalc"></div>
```

Comment: О спасибо большое, точно, можно же было в отдельную функцию запихать и потом реади делать ))

Comment: Галочку тык ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: да щас тыкну, забыл, а там же еще стрелки есть прибавить или отнять, когда их клик, с суммой ничего не происходит.

Comment: и не будет. это надо кастомный инпут делать... либо попробуй ещё событие `change` ко всему прочему....добавил в ответ